# C# console write to self (write to own inputstream)

Tags: c#, input, console, console-application

I would like to add data to my Console as if a user wrote it.

Eg:

```
Console.writeAsUser('Hello')
Console.writeline(Console.readline());
```

Such that the console will afterwards read:

```
Hello
Hello
```

From 1) fake-typing it 2) echoing it in the while loop

It is also okay if it's not fake-typed, just written into the input stream.

I want to read a file as if it were written into the console, to keep my input-parsing simpler. It could also help test interfaces automatically and simply.

Comment: How about just redirecting the file into the standard input?

Comment: It has to be done dynamically in the program. Just piping won't work. Can I get the Console's standard input? How do I write to it?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Prepare an interface, with needed methods (probably just `ReadLine()`), implement your parser to use that interface instead of `Console` class directly. Then prepare 2 interface implementations: one which uses `Console` and other which uses `File`, and pass one or another to your parser.

Comment: Do what @MarcinJuraszek said...However if you still want to access the standard input it is possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, that's not what I asked at all and blocking makes it nontrivial. I need a method to use Console and sometimes toss in a file. Rewriting Console with an extra features is NOT an elegant solution.

Comment: @TomerArazy, this only applies to subprocesses not to the currentprocess (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Lodewijk I see that's not what you've asked for, and that's exactly why I put it into a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I see that. I mean that aside from not being what I asked for your solution does not solve my problem. I have to parse one stream, that stream can have a "Load file" that has to be parsed like the first stream should be before any new input may come from the first stream.

Comment: Never actually tried it myself (never had the need) but isn't using Console.SetIn(...) sufficient? Just reset it to the default input stream once you're done reading the file. Related: [Console.In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You may get processor info and get `stdin_write`